# Msi Install issue on windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I have crated Msi Installer using visual studio setup and Install project.My set up is working fine on some machine but on it works fine only when I am installing that set up using command prompt with admin privilege else installer completed but I am not able to see any file in programme file. So what can be issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think Visual Studio generated MSIs behave badly when they require admin privilege but you don't use it. I think you'll find they install all the files to C:\ somewhere. The essential question is not if the files are there, oddly enough, but whether you see an entry in Add/Remove Programs (Programs&Features) because that means the install succeeded, because you don't mention an error the install rolling back. I think you are saying that there is an entry there.

Did you mark the install as for Everyone or Just me? That seems to make a difference, and I suspect you have a Just me install, which still means that you need admin privilege if you install to restricted locations. The Just me install does not mean a limited user can write to restricted parts of the system.

Comment: If I recall correctly, they schedule deferred CA's with impersonation.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have marked install by select option just me but it won't work.It copy installation file to c:\ at root and you right i am also able to see entry in Add\Remove section.I have use orca and Use Lock Permission for all user but it not helping me still is copy to c: drive.Is there way I can get file in program file?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I am not able to understand what you saying can you please explain in brief if possible.

Comment: CAs don't come into this. To repeat for the OP: VS setups get this issue when a Just me install attempts to install into program files, that requires privilege, so in its fallback it installs to C:\.  You can't install to Program Files from a limited user account! VS attempts to help by falling back to the C: drive.

Comment: can I Install it Program File by selecting Every One option instead just me?And One more thing I am not able to get UAC prompt at that machine?Is there any way so that I can get UAC prompt on machine?

Comment: Try Everyone, yes, but if it doesn't show the UAC elevation prompt or you are installing silently (which means there will not be a prompt) then it still won't work. Maybe UAC is turned off? Either way, turning of UAC does not mean that limited users can write to Program Files.